# How to disable deactivation button of admin app in Device Administration in android

Tags: android, mdm

I am working on android app where I have to use Samsung KNOX API for Mobile Device Management. So I activate admin using following code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mAdminName);
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
        "Your boss told you to do this");
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVATION_REQUEST);
```

After the activation I can easily deactivate the app from device administration using following steps:

Setting-> General-> Security-> Device Administrators-> Tap on the app and there will be a dialog box and I can deactivate this app using Deactivate button. So please help me to disable this Deactivate button so user will not be able to deactivate the application from device administration.

Comment: check my answer.......if you found useful upvote it.......

Comment: is your phone rooted?

Comment: @FarazAhmad I wanna do the same. Did you achieved this?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite straightforward to do using the Samsung KNOX SDK.  Here is the documentation: https://seap.samsung.com/api-references/android-standard/reference/android/app/enterprise/EnterpriseDeviceManager.html#setAdminRemovable(boolean)

Sample code:

```
edm = (EnterpriseDeviceManager) mContext.getSystemService
                       (EnterpriseDeviceManager.ENTERPRISE_POLICY_SERVICE);
edm.setAdminRemovable(false);
```